# use one table data on multiple tables mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in my MySQL databases  as shown below

this is the  user table and id is the primary key

```
+------+---------+------+
| id  | name | USERNAME |
+------+---------+------+
| 1   |   A  |          |
| 2   |   A  |   1      |
| 3   |   A  |   1      |
| 4   |   A  |   0      |
| 5   |   A  |   1      |
+------+-----+----------+
```

this is the second table called wallet ,it is empty and id foreign key

```
 +------+------+
 | id   |amount|
 +------+------+
```

how would I be able to duplicate all ids on the first table to the second one?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking for. Please clarify by posting an example

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are asking, could you try to be more specific with your question? It is the nature of SQL to have different tables each with their own data. In order to combine all that information and extract data that is relevant to you, you would write an SQL query. I might not understand what you are trying to do, but it seems to me like it would help you to read some introduction tutorials to SQL.

Comment: I would like  my  foreign key  which is id on the second table to hold data from the primary key on the first table which is  id

Comment: @Cerno i would like  duplicate all ids on the firs table to the second one

Comment: Your question could still use some work. Could be go into a little more detail about what you are trying to achieve? Normally, as you add entries to your second table, you would link them to corresponding entries of your first table. Question: If you want to copy the ids to the second table, how are you planning to fill your "amount" field for each entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems very simple

```
insert into wallet (id)
select id from user;
```